# Segue not appearing after Image Picker

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am writing an iOS app where, in a view there is a button. Clicking on that button gets an action sheet which has options to pick image from camera or gallery. After the image is picked, it should be passed on to another view by manually calling a segue. The image picker appears and the prepare for segue code is executed, but the segue doesnt appear. There are no errors and I have checked all identifiers etc. Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)showButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *photoActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from Library", nil];
    photoActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [photoActionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

     switch (buttonIndex) {
     case 0:
            {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
             picker.delegate = self;
             picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
             [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
             break;
            }
         case 1:
            {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
             UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
             picker.delegate = self;
             picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
             [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
             break;
            }
     default:
             break;

     }

}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToPhotoDetails"]){
        FostoPhotoDetailsViewController *photoDetails = (FostoPhotoDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        photoDetails.imageView.image = self.buttonImage1;
    }
}



- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    self.buttonImage1 = image;
    //FostoPhotoDetailsViewController *photoDetails = [[FostoPhotoDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    //photoDetails.imageView.image = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Test");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToPhotoDetails" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: how is your segue configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are executing a segue with style `push` without being inside a `UINavigationController`.

When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` it first correctly calls `prepareForSegue:sender:` then it tries to retrieve the current navigation controller and push the destination controller doing something like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
```

But since you are not inside a `UINavigationController` the property `navigationController` is set to `nil`, causing the above call to fail silently.

Either change the display style of your segue to something other than `push` (for instance `modal`) or embed you controller in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. It's working now. Though the image I am trying to pass to the second view is still not displaying.

Comment: open another question on that specific issue and I'll be glad to help you